# create a symmetric matrix from a pairwise list python for clustering scikit, DBSCAN

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, dbscan

My goal is to perform clustering using DBSCAN from scikit with a precomputed similarity matrix.
I have a list with features. I do a pairwise to generate unique pairs for the list and have a function that calculates similarity between pairs. Now I want to transform it to a symmetric matrix that can be used as an input for the clustering algorithm.
I think groupby may be helpful, but I am not sure how to go about it. Here is a sample code that gives a list of pairs with distance measure.The id field in the original list is the unique row identifier.

```
def add_similarity(listdict):
    random.seed(10)
    newlistdist=[]
    for tup_dict in listdict:
        newdict={}
        tup0=tup_dict[0]
        tup1=tup_dict[1]
        for key,value in tup0.items():
            newdict[key +"_1"]=value
        for key,value in tup1.items():
            newdict[key+"_2"]=value 
        newdict["similarity"]=random.random()      
        newlistdist.append(newdict)                   
    return newlistdist


def generatesymm():
    listdict =[{'feature1': 4, 'feature2':2,"id": 100},{'feature1': 3, 'feature2': 2,"id":200},{'feature1': 4, 'feature2':2,"id": 300}]
    pairs=list(itertools.combinations(listdict, 2) )
    newlistdict=add_similarity(pairs)
```

If I run this code this gives

```
    [{'id_2': 200, 'feature1_2': 3, 'feature2_2': 2, 'feature2_1': 2, 'feature1_1': 4, 'similarity': 0.571, 'id_1': 100},     


{'id_2': 300, 'feature1_2': 4, 'feature2_2': 2, 'feature2_1': 2, 'feature1_1': 4, 'similarity': 0.42, 'id_1': 100},   


{'id_2': 300, 'feature1_2': 4, 'feature2_2': 2, 'feature2_1': 2, 'feature1_1': 3, 'similarity': 0.578, 'id_1': 200}]
```

The output I need

```
          100       200       300


100        1         0.571      0.42  


200        0.571      1          0.578


300        0.428      0.578       1
```

Comment: How about using a `for` loop, and storing the value once in `[x,y]` ad oncein `[y,x]`?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse
doing this with a for loop is not really viable with large matrices. You will likely run into memory issues.

Comment: @ColinAnthony The memory issues are not related to whether you use for loops, or not. *Precomputed* matrix approaches always scale badly, but that is his requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear to me where `id_3` comes from, but below is one way to make your dataframe.  The trick is to use numpy to index into the upper and lower triangular portions of the matrix.

```
In [679]:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
similarities = [x["similarity"] for x in newlistdict]
names = ['id_'+str(x) for x in range(1,4)]
n = len(similarities)
iuu = np.mask_indices(3, np.triu, 1)
iul = np.mask_indices(3, np.tril, -1)
mat = np.eye(n)
mat[iuu] = similarities
mat[iul] = similarities
df = pd.DataFrame(mat,columns=names)
df.index = names
df

Out[679]:
        id_1        id_2        id_3
id_1    1.000000    0.896082    0.897818
id_2    0.896082    1.000000    0.186298
id_3    0.897818    0.186298    1.000000
```

(The values differ from your question because I don't know the random seed you used.)

Comment: The id field in the original list ( before pairwise) contains the unique id of a record. After pairwise, each row is uniquely identified by  values in the colnames id_1, id_2.  Finally  [id_1][id_3] should have similarity value for  records with value  id=1 and id=3. If the original list had 5 records, pairwise gives 10 combinations. Matrix is 10*10 where row and col names correspond to  unique values of the original id field.